# Add a document name, while using an external document reference

Tags: cross-referencing, titles, xr

I'm using `xr` package for referencing to external documents. I want to add external document title to a reference.

How it could be obtained?

Comment: Seems difficult, see the discussion below: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/493925/xr-cross-reference-change-colour-for-external-references-only

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following.  If you set up xr so that `\ref{A-mnemonic}` returns the section number, then `\ref{A-name}` will return "document name".  As a bonus, `\pageref{A-name}` will return the last page number.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\AtEndDocument{\def\@currentlabel{document name}%
\label{name}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section{Section}\label{mnemonic}

\ref{mnemonic}

\ref{name}

\pageref{name}
\end{document}
```